# Import wallet from cli to composer REST server

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to import a wallet directly from my command line interface to my composer REST server - does anyone know how to do this?

Usually, I go to my composer REST server and import it by selecting the `.card` file and adding the name in the POST `/wallet/import` method on the composer REST server.

But I would like to streamline this process for my demo so that all cards are automatically imported into my REST server using a shell program that sets up my network.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each request you make in the Explorer of the REST server you see an equivalent `curl` command. e.g. `curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' --header 'Accept: application/json' {"type":"formData"} 'http://localhost:3000/api/wallet/import?name=mycard'`

curl commands can be used in scripts so it should be possible to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks R Thatcher. If I do that however, I get an error message: `Error","message":"Authorization Required`. Can we authorize with Github via the cli?

Comment: I would think so - but I haven't done it.   After you have authorized you will also have to pass the token as another `--header` for the curl command.